# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease

Tags: android, android-studio

Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease

> Com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/printHelper$printHelperStublmpl.class

My gradle properties

```
android {
    compileSdkversion 26
    BuildToolsversion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationID "com.blaze.buildbox"
        MinSdkversion 14
        Targeted Sdkversion 26
        MultiDexEnabled true

        ndk {
            moduleName "player_shared"
        }

        dexOptions{
            JavaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }
    }
    BuildTypes {
        Release {
            minifyEnabled false
            ProgaurdFile getDefaultProgaurdFile('progaurd-android.txt'),'progaurd-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    sourceSets.main{
        Jni.srcDirs=[]
    }
}

dependencies

    Compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-service:+) { exclude module : 'support-v4'}
    Compile files ('Libs/javax.inject-1.2.2.jar')
    Compile files('Libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    Compile files('Libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')

}
```